# Android AOSP modification errors out

Tags: java, android, android-source, unsupported-class-version

I am trying to understand the flow of code in the native android. For the same, I downloaded the Android source code and built images for my android device. 
I have the following java and javac versions in my system.

1. javac 1.7.0_79
2. java version "1.7.0_79"

When I make, every thing works as expected. i am able to create images and my device boots with those as well. Now I added some simple Logs on some the files like: **Android/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java** and performed a make again. I get the error : **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/doclava/Doclava : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**. I am not able to understand why I get this error when I just add a few Logs in one of the files. It should have occurred right at the first make as well, or not? I read a lot about this error and found it is because of the mismatch between run time and compile time versions. But I have Java 1.7 and javac 1.7. Anyone faced this before?

Comment: Do you have any other Java version installed?
Make sure you do build with java 1.7 in your IDE

Comment: @kolakao: Yes I have java 1.6 as well. But I made sure that Java and javac 1.7 is used with this command: update-alternatives --config java and update-alternatives --config javac.